# In python, how to use queues properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So far I have the following:

```
fnamw = input("Enter name of file:")
def carrem(fnamw):
    s = Queue( )
    for line in fnamw:
        s.enqueue(line)
    return s

 print(carrem(fnamw))
```

The above doesn't print a list of the numbers in the file that I input instead the following is obtained:

```
<__main__.Queue object at 0x0252C930>
```

Answer (score 1):

When printing a `Queue`, you're just printing the object directly, which is why you get that result.

You don't want to print the object representation, but I'm assuming you want to print the contents of the Queue. To do so you need to call the `get` method of the Queue. It's worth noting that in doing so, you will exhaust the Queue.

Replacing `print(carrem(fnamw))` with `print(carrem(fnamw).get())` should print the first item of the Queue.

If you really just want to print the list of items in the Queue, you should just use a list. Queue are specifically if you're looking for a FIFO (first-in-first-out) data structure.

Comment: i think i might be able to this using list but i would to learn using queues or stacks and i know it can be done

Comment: @rggod Use Queues when you have a reason to use Queues. Trying to fit them into awkward situations where they don't make sense will only confuse you, and people reading your code.

Comment: but just doing the above is not where im stopping, i trying to remove flip values so i thought queues would be the best way to go

Comment: What are flip values? Also if you think you might need a Queue later, I would suggest asking a question about that instead. Printing the list of values in a Queue is not something that you can do without exhausting the Queue.

Comment: i wanted to verify if my queue is reciving data?

Comment: @rggod Then my above answer should have you covered.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46996/discussion-between-rggod-and-slater-tyranus)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you don't actually have any need for a `Queue` in that program. A `Queue` is used primarily for synchronization and data transfer in multithreaded programming. And it really doesn't seem as if that is what you're attempting to do.

For you usage, you could just as well use an ordinary Python list:

```
fnamw = input("Enter name of file:")
def carrem(fnamw):
    s = []
    for line in fnamw:
        s.append(line)
    return s

print(carrem(fnamw))
```

On that same note, however, you're not actually reading the file. The program as you quoted it will simply put each character in the filename as a post of its own into the list (or Queue). What you really want is this:

```
def carrem(fnamw):
    s = []
    with open(fnamw) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            s.append(line)
    return s
```

Or, even simpler:

```
def carrem(fnamw):
    with open(fnamw) as fp:
        return list(fp)
```